# (mySql) query to match /exact_string/[wild card]/exact_string/[wild card] etc?

Tags: mysql, regex, match

My URLs look like

'/api/comments/languages/124/component/segment_translation/2'

I've know which parts of the url are static; and which are dynamic - and have a structure which tells me this

I have example requests and responses (where the dynamic parts won't match) - which I'm trying to look up in mySQL - so I could very easily generate a query

```
select url from qb_log_full_requests 
where 
URL REGEXP 'api/comments/languages/[^f.*]/component/[^f.*]/[^f.*]'
```

Which is great; except it doesn't work.

Is there a way to ask mySQL to match

> /exact_string/[wild card]/exact_string/[wild card]

etc?

Comment: When you put the `.*` inside of the character class (`[ ... ]`) it means you're looking for those characters.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may try following regexp:

/api/comments/languages/[^/]+/component/segment_translation/[^/]+